# Is ASP.NET Identity framework compatible on windows 8.1 store apps

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

I am using windows identity for an mvc web application. I want to make a windows store app that also uses the authentication the web app users to authenticate login/registering, that is the ASP.NET Identity framework, the latest one with VS2013.

Are windows phones able to use the identity framework through some sort of API, or are they not compatible.

If they are compatible is there an example that I can reference, I can't seem to work out what I have to do to integrate my phone app with ASP.NET Identity.